# Regular Expression for parsing apache error log files

Tags: regex, apache, logging

I would need a regular expression to be used in a Java program for parsing apache error files, such as:

```
[Thu Sep 27 12:08:18 2012] [error] [client 151.10.158.10] File does not exist: /srv/www/htdocs/pad/favicon.ico
[Thu Oct 04 17:02:42 2012] [error] [client 151.10.1.10] File does not exist: > /srv/www/htdocs/pad/favicon.ico
[Wed Oct 17 10:16:40 2012] [error] [client 151.10.14.60] File does not exist: /srv/www/htdocs/pad/sites/all/modules/fckeditor/fckeditor/editor/userfiles, referer: http://pad.sta.uniroma1.it/sites/all/modules/fckeditor/fckeditor/editor/fckeditor.html?InstanceName=edit-body&Toolbar=DrupalFull
```

I already tried several solutions (some of which have been previously reported on stackoverflow), the one that seems to work better is:

```
^(\[[\w:\s]+\]) (\[[\w]+\]) (\[[\w\d.\s]+\])?([\w\s/.(")-]+[\-:]) ([\w/\s]+)$
```

However, it seems to be unable to match strings like:

```
[Thu May 17 22:41:54 2012] [error] [client 118.238.211.206] Invalid URI in request GET :81/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1
```

How do can I fix it?

**EDIT**
I checked all the proposed solutions and, although improving the number of matched lines, all of them are still unable to deal with cases like the following ones:

```
[Fri Jul 15 00:24:41 2011] [error] [client 219.12.35.141] script '/srv/www/htdocs/pad2/scripts/setup.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon May 28 18:43:25 2012] [error] [client 88.110.28.25] Invalid URI in request GET HTTP/1.1 HTTP/1.1
```

Notice also that it would be ok for me to receive in a single group all the data following the square brackets including the client keyword

Comment: Could you explain, what data you want to receive? Capture all `[...]` group and end of line?

Comment: Namely, I am interested in receiving the information encoded in the first three [...] groups, plus a fourth group containing all the remaining text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> receiving the information encoded in the first three [...] groups

Find `[...]` as longest string starting with `[` and ending with `]` without other `]` symbol between them - `\[[^\]]+\]`

Rest of line capture as `.*` - match from current position to end of line.

So your full solution looks like this:

```
^(\[[^\]]+\]) (\[[^\]]+\]) (\[[^\]]+\]) (.*)$
```

[RegEx demo](http://regex101.com/r/iV8eT9/2)

Comment: Hey, your post showed up in the Low Quality Posts queue. Might want to complete the answer by adding details and addressing the question.

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would match all the above mentioned error formats.

```
^(\[[\w:\s]+\]) (\[[\w]+\]) (\[[\w\d.\s]+\])?([\w\s\/.(")-]+[\-:])\s*>?\s*([\w\/\s.]+)(?:\s*,(\s*\w+:)\s*([\w\/.=?:&-]+))?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eM1xP0/4)

Answer (score 0):

There is no space after the column in "GET :81"

This one works :

```
^(\[[\w:\s]+\]) (\[[\w]+\]) (\[[\w\d.\s]+\])?([\w\s\/.(")-]+[\-:])\s?([\w\/\s.]+)
```

example : http://regex101.com/r/xO1wG2/2

Answer (score 0):

Last segment of your regex doesn't seem right. This simplified regex should work:

```
^(\[[\w:\s]+\]) (\[[\w]+\]) (\[[\w\d.\s]+\]) ([\s\w/.(")-]+[-:])(.+)$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fT6fR9/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $a="[Thu May 17 22:41:54 2012] [error] [client 118.238.211.206] Invalid URI in request GET :81/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1\n";
 $a .="[Thu May 17 22:41:54 2012] [error] [client 118.238.211.206] Invalid URI in request GET :81/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1\n";
 $a .="[Thu May 17 22:41:54 2012] [error] [client 118.238.211.206] Invalid URI in request GET :81/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1\n";
preg_match_all("/(\[.*\])\s+(\[.*\])\s+(\[.*\])\s+([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+:)\s*(.*)/",$a,$m) ; var_dump($m);
```

try this ... (out put)

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '[Thu May 17 22:41:54 2012] [error] [client 118.238.211.206] Invalid URI in request GET :81/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1' (length=128)
      1 => string '[Thu May 17 22:41:54 2012] [error] [client 118.238.211.206] Invalid URI in request GET :81/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1' (length=128)
      2 => string '[Thu May 17 22:41:54 2012] [error] [client 118.238.211.206] Invalid URI in request GET : 81/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1' (length=129)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '[Thu May 17 22:41:54 2012]' (length=26)
      1 => string '[Thu May 17 22:41:54 2012]' (length=26)
      2 => string '[Thu May 17 22:41:54 2012]' (length=26)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '[error]' (length=7)
      1 => string '[error]' (length=7)
      2 => string '[error]' (length=7)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '[client 118.238.211.206]' (length=24)
      1 => string '[client 118.238.211.206]' (length=24)
      2 => string '[client 118.238.211.206]' (length=24)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Invalid URI in request GET :' (length=28)
      1 => string 'Invalid URI in request GET :' (length=28)
      2 => string 'Invalid URI in request GET :' (length=28)
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '81/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1' (length=40)
      1 => string '81/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1' (length=40)
      2 => string '81/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1' (length=40)
```